# Show and Hide Progress Bar in Page_Load

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have implemented some web-page in ASP.NET. I want to add a progress bar to my page. Because the page takes several minutes to load.

I want to put *show Progress bar function* at the start of Page_Load function. And hide it at the end of the Page_Load function. How can I implement this?

Please give me some advice. Thank you in advance.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #loading
        {
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 10pt;
            border: 5px solid #67CFF5;
            width: 220px;
            height: 20px;
            display: none;
            position: fixed;
            background-color: White;
            z-index: 999;

            text-align: center;
            line-height: 20px;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ToggleProgressBar() {
            var loading = window.jQuery('#loading');
            if (loading.is(':visible')) {
                loading.hide();
            }
            else {
                var top = Math.max(parseInt($(window).height() / 2 - loading.height() / 2), 0);
                var left = Math.max(parseInt($(window).width() / 2 - loading.width() / 2), 0);
                loading.css({ top: top, left: left });
                loading.show();
            }
        }

        function blahblah(s, e) {
            // some blah blah function contents
        }

        function blahblah2(s, e) {
            // some blah blah function contents
        }
    </script>

    <script runat="server">
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            **// TODO: Show Progress Bar**

            DelayTime(); // dummy function to delay page load

            **// TODO: Hide Progress Bar**
        }

        protected void DelayTime()
        {
            txt_delay.InnerText = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < 3000; i++)
            {
                txt_delay.InnerHtml += i.ToString("0000") + ", ";
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <span id="txt_delay" runat="server"></span>

        <div id="loading" align="center" runat="server">
            Loading...
            <%--<img src="/Images/progress-indicator.gif" alt="" />--%>
        </div>      
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: **[Demo 1](http://projects.lukehaas.me/css-loaders/)**, **[Demo 2](https://www.freshdesignweb.com/jquery-css3-loading-progress-bar/)**

Comment: i Like @GuruprasadRao Demo also  You can use a plugin such as jQuery BlockUI to do this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way would be to give your css a class. Then put a div as a placeholder where you want the window to show. Give the div an id and assign it's css class the id of your class and set the display attribute to none. Then when you are ready use a bit of jquery to change the display from none to say block. assuming you have done something like div id='myWait' display='none' class='mycssclass'
then jquery along the lines ('#myWait').attr('display','block');